# ListTile showing all elements rather than just the elements that are needed

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-futurebuilder

**ISSUE**
Hi, I have a Map as a field within firebase called "fifthQuestion" which consists of two options ("Black" or "Brown"). When a user selects one of these options they are saved in firebase as a boolean. My code (See below) is currently showing the correct element (The user selected "Black"), however it is showing it twice (One time for the "Black" index and one time for the "Brown" index -- even though "Brown was not selected). How can I edit my code to only show the indexes of elements that were selected (Marked as true) by the user rather than showing the correct element but multiple times (however many indexes there are even if they weren't marked as true)?

Any help would be much appreciated and thank you in advance.

**SCREENSHOT FROM FIREBASE**

[image]

**SCREENSHOT FROM APP**

[image]
**CURRENT CODE**

```
if(snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
                                Map<String, dynamic> data = snapshot.data!.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
                                Map<String, dynamic> firstQuestion = data["fifthQuestion"];
                                List<String> keys = firstQuestion.keys.where((key) => firstQuestion[key] == true).toList();
                                var isTrue = keys;
                                return Column(
                                  children: [
                                    new ListTile(
                                      dense: true,
                                      tileColor: SkapeColors.pageBackground,
                                      title: Row(
                                        children: [
                                          Container(
                                            width: 250,
                                            child:
                                            new Text(
                                              isTrue[0],
                                              style: TextStyle(
                                                fontSize: 16,
                                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                                letterSpacing: 0.5,
                                                color: Colors.white,
                                              ),
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                          Icon(Icons.check_circle, color: SkapeColors.colorPrimary,).paddingOnly(left: 20),
                                        ],
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                );
                              }
```

Comment: What do you get if you print `isTrue`

Answer (score 0):

**SOLUTION**

```
                Card(
              child: new FutureBuilder(
                future: jobs.doc(widget.jobId).get(),
                builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<DocumentSnapshot> snapshot) {
                  if(snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
                    Map<String, dynamic> data = snapshot.data!.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
                    Map<String, dynamic> firstQuestion = data["firstQuestion"];
                    List<String> keys = firstQuestion.keys.where((key) => firstQuestion[key] == true).toList();
                    var isTrue = keys;
                    return ListView.builder(
                        shrinkWrap: true,
                        // key: PageStorageKey<String>("Color Preference"),
                        physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                        itemCount: keys.length,
                        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                          return Column(
                            children: [
                              new ListTile(
                                dense: true,
                                tileColor: SkapeColors.pageBackground,
                                title: Row(
                                  children: [
                                    Container(
                                      width: 250,
                                      child:
                                      new Text(
                                        isTrue[index],
                                        style: TextStyle(
                                          fontSize: 16,
                                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                          letterSpacing: 0.5,
                                          color: Colors.white,
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    Icon(Icons.check_circle,
                                      color: SkapeColors.colorPrimary,)
                                        .paddingOnly(left: 20),
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ),
                            ],
                          );
                        }
                    );
                  }
                  return Container();
                },

              ),
            )
```